# Conforming to Equatable vs defining func ==

Tags: swift

Let's say I want to check two objects (btw: is it correct to talk about objects when it is a Struct, not a Class ? Should I say "two constants" ?) for equality by comparing the id. Example below shows that both versions - with and without conforming to Equatable - work. Should I still use the Equatable version ?

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let p1 = Person(id: 123, comment: "some comment")
        let p2 = Person(id: 123, comment: "some other comment")
        print(p1 == p2) //true

        let op1 = OtherPerson(id: 456, comment: "just another comment")
        let op2 = OtherPerson(id: 456, comment: "one more comment")
        print(op1 == op2) //true

    }
}

struct Person : Equatable {
    var id: Int
    var comment: String

    static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.id == rhs.id)
    }
}

struct OtherPerson { //no : Equatable
    var id: Int
    var comment: String

    static func == (lhs: OtherPerson, rhs: OtherPerson) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.id == rhs.id)
    }
}
```

Comment: The official documentation recommends the term “instances”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically asking why we have protocols at all. 
We don't have to speak about operators, exactly the same is valid for any protocol with methods, e.g:

```
protocol Closable {
   func close()
}

struct A {
   func close() {}
}

struct B: Closable {
   func close() {}
}

let a = A()
a.close() // valid even without protocol

let b = B()
b.close() // valid with protocol
```

`Equatable` just says that some type has `==` operator defined. Thanks to the protocol we can define methods that work on all types conforming to the protocol, for example:

```
func <T: Closable>doSomething(closable: T) {
   ...
   closable.close()
}
```

Without the protocol, we would have to define such a method for every type (`A` and `B`) separately. Protocols provide common interface that allows us to constrain the definition of other types. `Equatable` is very important in that regard because it is used heavily in the standard library.

For example:

```
let personList1 = [OtherPerson(id: "123"), OtherPerson(id: "124")]
let personList2 = [OtherPerson(id: "123"), OtherPerson(id: "124")]

let listsAreEqual = (personList1 == personList2) // won't compile
```

Why the example won't compile? Because `==` for Arrays is defined only if `Element` conforms to `Equatable`. It is not enough for `==` operator to exist.

Another typical use case is `Array.contains`. Without `Equatable`, that method won't work.

Declaring the type as `Equatable` won't cost you anything but it will give you many benefits immediately.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, but when I tried your example it did not work for other reason - "'OtherPerson.Type' is not convertible to '(Int, String) -> OtherPerson'". Had to replace the array and set it to:  let personList1 = [op1, op2] and then I noticed that Equatable is missing due to the compiler error. Adding Equatable made it work.

Comment: @bdskfsdk321dsad3 I just skipped the `comment` from your example. That's why the initializer did not work for you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary, but it helps when you want to pass your objects to a generic function that takes `Equatable`.

For example we may extend `Array` with a custom filter:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    var unique: [Element] {
        var res: [Element] = []
        for item in self {
            if !res.contains(item) {
                res += [item]
            }
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

Defined this way, any `Array` of `Equatable` will get `unique` function automatically. Also, Swift common library defines a lot of `Array` methods which is only available with `Equatable` and/or `Hashable` objects.

I suggest to conform to all available protocols whenever possible. Conforming to `Equatable` doesn't really cost you anything at this point but it gives you a lot of benefits. After all, they call Swift the "protocol-oriented programming language".

Comment: Also, `[Element] == [Element]` is defined only when `Element: Equatable`. Also `Hashable`. There is a ton of similar examples when `Equatable` is really necessary.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks! My point was you can create your own function which will benefit from conforming to a protocol.